python time complexity in leetcode problem
i was doind a leetcode problem called "minimum absolute difference" and my code worked when i ran it but in the submission i got the error Time Limit Exceeded
this is the quetion description:
Given an array of distinct integers arr, find all pairs of elements with the minimum absolute difference of any two elements.
this is the code:
class Solution(object):
    def minimumAbsDifference(self, arr):
        arr.sort()
        s = 1000
        t = []
        for i in arr:
            if (abs(i - arr[(arr.index(i))-1])) < s:
                s = (abs(i - arr[(arr.index(i))-1]))
        for i in arr:
            if  (abs(arr[(arr.index(i))-1] - i)) == s:
                t.append([arr[arr.index(i)-1],i])
        return t


Why are you using arr[arr.index(i))...] ? Can't you just change your loop to for x in range(len(arr)): and use arr[i] instead of looking up the index?

@RScop or, even better, you can use for i, x in enumerate(arr)

See the Leetcode solution by neicene111 for the same general approach but more efficient.

You can do it in one iteration:
def minimumAbsDifference(self, arr: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
    result = []
    if len(arr) < 2:
        return result
    arr.sort()
    
    min_diff = 1 + arr[-1] - arr[0]
    for idx in range(1,len(arr)):
        diff = arr[idx] - arr[idx-1]
        if diff < min_diff:
            result = []
            min_diff = diff
        
        if diff == min_diff:
            result.append([arr[idx-1], arr[idx]])
    return result


Your algorithm degrades to O(²) time complexity because of using arr.index(i). The first time this returns quickly, because i is found at index 0, but the next iterations will need to look further and further in the array to find the match.
You could get the list of consecutive values from the sorted list:
        pairs = list(zip(arr, arr[1:]))

Then, get the minimimum among those (your first loop):
        mindiff = min((b - a for a, b in pairs))

And finally, filter the pairs to those that have that difference (your second loop):
        return [pair for pair in pairs if pair[1] - pair[0] == mindiff]

Taken together:
class Solution:
    def minimumAbsDifference(self, arr: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        arr.sort()
        pairs = list(zip(arr, arr[1:]))
        mindiff = min((b - a for a, b in pairs))
        return [pair for pair in pairs if pair[1] - pair[0] == mindiff]


You have multiple iterations over the input list when one pass is all you need.
Also, setting s = 1000 may work for the test data but it's not a general solution.
Try this:
class Solution:
    def minimumAbsDifference(self, arr: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        result = []
        arr.sort()
        a = arr[0]
        mad = arr[-1] - a
        for b in arr[1:]:
            diff = b - a
            if diff < mad:
                result = [[a, b]]
                mad = diff
            elif diff == mad:
                result.append([a, b])
            a = b
        return result

